# Group by in linq for email alert

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class:

```
public class CustomerEmailAlert
{
  public string EmailId { get; set; }
  public string Interest1 {get;set;}
  public string Interest2 {get;set;}     
}
```

The result from sql is something like this:

    `+---------------+-----------+-----------+
    |     Email     | Interest1 | Interest2 | 
    +---------------+-----------+-----------+
    | abc@gmail.com | Burrito   | Apple     |
    | abc@gmail.com | Pizza     | Milk      |
    | abc@gmail.com | Apple     | Burrito   |
    | def@gmail.com | Milk      | Banana    |
    +---------------+-----------+-----------+`

I have mapped the result using `Dapper` to `List<CustomerEmailAlert>`

`List<CustomerEmailAlert>= con.Query<CustomerEmailAlert>("getalerts", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();`

My question is: How do I group Customers by Email so that the email they receive contains their interests (they should receive only **1 copy of email**)

I have tried this: [Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Comment: what is your expected result and where do u want group in sql or in linqq?

Comment: uh `var groups = list.GroupBy(x => x.Email);`

Comment: You tried... so what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group this way:

```
var result= from e in list
            group new {e.Interest1,e.Interest2} by e.Email into g
            select new {Email=g.Key, Interests=g.ToList()};
```